# Why can't I get a 201 code with this POST HTTParty post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, httparty

Trying to send a post request to create a 'task' using Closeio's api.  I'm getting  a 200, and the 'task' isn't being posted to the website. The message is returning "OK".  I've tried reformatting the params/options all day.  What am I doing wrong? any ideas?

Here's the post request:

```
url = 'https://app.close.io/api/v1/task'

         params = {
                "lead_id" => 'lead_xxxxx....',
                "assigned_to" => 'user_yyyyyyyyy.....', 
                "text" => "This customer has been referred",
                "due_date" => Date.today.to_s,
                "is_complete" => false
              }


        response = HTTParty.post( url , { 

                :body => params.to_json,
                :basic_auth => {
                            :username => [API_KEY], 
                            :password => ' '
                            },
                :headers => { 
                              'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
                              }
       })
```

response:

```
@response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=UTF-8"], "date"=>["Sat, 14 Mar 2015 20:19:38 GMT"], "server"=>["ElasticWWW"], "set-cookie"=>["session=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/"], "strict-transport-security"=>["max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"], "vary"=>["Accept"], "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "content-length"=>["73861"], "connection"=>["Close"]}>
```

Comment: Check response body. Seems like it contains error description in HTML format (look at size in `Content-Length` header).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yeah, the response is returning just a giant object of all the tasks created previously.  I can't find any error key in the object?

Comment: hm, this is strange. Seems like API handle it as GET request. Try to [enable logging](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/655ef5ff9983442fb7d3e4bfea874f2f23859af5/examples/logging.rb#L26). I think it help to investigate problem.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused: what info could/should be passed into the logger that I couldn't get from the development.log or the request info/variables from better errors?